# MS Custom Translator Capitalization

Tags: microsoft-translator

I trained a German custom model and get better translations from it but it is making lots of mistakes in the capitalization, like:

KundenDienstMitarbeiter, Produkt ÄnderungsBenachrichtigungen , or FERNSEHgeräte

The general MS model does not seem to have this issue so I wonder if I could clean my data to somehow avoid this issue.

I have found out that the issue is happening when capitalization in titles and names is in the source. The German translations basically retain the capitalization although the rule for the compound nouns would only capitalize the first letter.
Source: Message Preferences

MT: BenachrichtigungsEinstellungen

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I'm having similar problem with both custom and generic engine on Asian languages: e.g. when you translate "If WebDAV is not set to allowed, enable the WebDAV protocol." to Japanese of Chinese in Bing Translator, you get lowercase "webdav". Strangely, when you remove the second "WebDAV" from the sentence, the translation will be capitalized correctly on Japanese, but not on Chinese...